# React Bootstrap Tabs - Keep Current Tab On Page Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm DELETING data from my database via an API call, then returning data from my database via another API call, but the 'Car' tab doesn't seem to update or refresh showing the new data.

I want to refresh the tab page via STATE or via a page reload and keep the user's selected tab using React Bootstrap, either:

- reload just the TAB the user is in
- RELOAD the whole page whilst keeping the TAB selected

React Bootstrap Tabs

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example" className="mb-3">
  <Tab eventKey="bus" title="Bus">
    <Bus />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="car" title="Car">
    <Car />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="van" title="Van">
    <Van />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>;
```

myFile.js:

```
const Car = () => {
  const [car, setCar] = useState([{ '': '' }]);
  const [selectedCar, setSelectedCar] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const data = await getCompanyCar(car.id);
        setCar(data)
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <CarModal car={selectedCar} onCancel={() => setSelectedCar(null)} />

      <Table className="p-4 rounded-3" striped>
        <thead className="bold fs-5" style={{ color: 'rgb(80, 80, 80)' }}>
          <tr style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <span className="text-nowrap" style={{ width: '0px' }}>
              Car
            </span>
            <button className="addButton" onClick={null}>
              Add
            </button>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {/* TODO:PAGINATE ROWS */}
          {car.map((car) => (
            <React.Fragment key={car.client_id}>
              <CarRow car={car} setSelectedCar={setSelectedCar} />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};

function CarFunction({ car, setSelectedCar }) {
  const [showConfirmResetModal, setShowConfirmResetModal] = useState(false);

  const handleDelete = async (event) => {
    try {
      const data = await deleteCompanyCar(Car.id);
      if (data[0].completed === 'deleted') {
        getCompanyCar(Car);
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      alert('Error, unable to delete');
    }
  };
  return (
    <ConfirmationModal
      header="Confirm Deletion"
      show={showConfirmResetModal}
      onHide={() => setShowConfirmResetModal(false)}
      onConfirm={handleDelete}
      annimation
    >
      Are you sure you want to delete this car?
    </ConfirmationModal>
  );
}

export default CarFunction;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You generally shouldn't be refreshing pages _or_ components manually. If your data is bound properly it will update. The question in your title is an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). I suggest revising to ask about the actual data issue.

Comment: To clarify further, I don't see you calling `setCar` anywhere. Also, your array variable should probably be `cars` (plural). Same with the component name.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks for responding! Regarding the data issue: I get all the data I need back from the API, it just doesn't update unless I do a page reload.

Also, updated the code where the setCar is called, good spot!